# Hibernate one-to-many and many-to-use. How to reference existing values instead of inserting publicated

Tags: hibernate, duplicates, entity, one-to-many, many-to-one

How can I force Hibernate not to insert duplicate values into a table of interest, but just to reference existing ones?

Here is an example:

**Gender entity:**

```
@Entity(name = "genders")
public class GenderEntity {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "gender_id")
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Integer id;

  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  @Column(name = "value")
  private GenderEnum value;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "gender", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  private Set<Person> genderNames = new HashSet<>();
}
```

**Person entity:**

```
NameWeightDescriptionEntity {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
  @Column(name = "name_id")
  private Integer id;

  @Column(name = "name", unique = true, nullable = false)
  private String name;

  @Column(name = "weight", nullable = false)
  private Short weight;

  @Column(name = "description", unique = true, nullable = false)
  private String description;


  @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinColumn(name = "gender_id")
  private GenderEntity gender;
}
```

The idea is when one creates a person at sets its gender as:

```
person.setGender(new GenderEntity() {{ setValue(GenderEnum.M); }});
```

and Hibernate always tries to create a **new** gender record.

What is needed is the following: Hibernate inserts as many new records in the database as many distinct enum values are provided for GenderEntity. In my case, just 2, since GenderEnum is very simple:

```
public enum GenderEnum {
  M,
  F
}
```

So if one types in its code:

```
person1.setGender(new GenderEntity() {{ setValue(GenderEnum.M); }});
person2.setGender(new GenderEntity() {{ setValue(GenderEnum.F); }});
person3.setGender(new GenderEntity() {{ setValue(GenderEnum.M); }});
```

then only **two** records must be created in GenderEntity's database table.

Currenly, there will be 3 row which is not what is expected.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like with **new** that is impossible. The only solution is apparently to move **GenderEntity** creation outside of *person* objects in order to reference them in the code.

References works fine.